# ___wglewCreateContextAttribsARB unresolved extern symbol

Tags: c++, c, winapi, opengl

I am currently working on a opengl window creation, and I added:

```
h_OGLContext = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(h_DeviceContext, NULL, attributes);
```

I am including(in this order):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wingdi.h>
#include <string>
#include "Vector.hpp"
#include "Color.hpp"
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\wglew.h>
```

I am linking against:

```
opengl32.lib
glew32.lib
```

But still this single error ._.

EDIT: I am using MSVS 2015 Community

Comment: No need to include wingdi.h if windows.h is included

Comment: dont makes a difference in my code

Comment: It's in glew32.lib. Just tested in MSVC2015. So, you might be linking it incorrectly.

Comment: What happens if you swap the order of the two `.lib` files?

Comment: actually nothing ._. thx for the suggestion !

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86892/wglcreatecontextattribsarb-is-undefined

Comment: This solved it, thank you for(;;)cout<<"very"; much !